# AngularJS: Only shows filtered content on last tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-filter

I wanted to use angular filters within bootstrap tabs. However, only the last tab shows me the filtered content the rest of the tabs are unresponsive ("Professionals" tab)

**Markup**

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="exploreController as exploreCtrl"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="Tabs">
        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(1)}" >
        <a aria-controls="project" role="tab" ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(1)">Projects</a></li>

        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(2)}" >
        <a aria-controls="team" role="tab" ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(2)">Teams</a></li>

        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(3)}" >
        <a aria-controls="prof" role="tab" ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(3)">Professionals</a></li> 

<div class="tab-content">
        <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
        <li ng-repeat = "proteam in exploreCtrl.proteams | filter:exploreCtrl.filtText">

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">

</div>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="media-heading">{{proteam.name}} </h2>
        <span class="label label-danger">{{proteam.tag1}}</span>
        <p>{{proteam.description}}
        </p></div></div></li></ul></div>
```

**Javascript**
This is where 'setTab' and 'checkTab' are used to ensure `ng-click` and `ng-class` are getting the correct values.

```
var app = angular.module('exploresModule',[]);
app.controller('exploreController',function() {

     this.tab=1;
    this.filtText = '';
    var proteams = [
        {
            name:'Ziyad Alvi',
            tag1:'C++',
            type:'prof'
        },
        {
            name:'Organic Foods',
            tag1:'food',
            type:'project'
        },
        {
            name:'Telekenisis',
            tag1:'Xmen',
            type:'project'
        } ];

    this.proteams = proteams;

    this.select = function(setTab) {
        this.tab = setTab;

        if (setTab === 1) { this.filtText = 'project'; }
        if (setTab === 2) { this.filtText = 'team'; }
        if (setTab === 3) { this.filtText = 'prof'; }
        else this.filtText = '';
    };

    this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
       return this.tab === checkTab;
    }
});
```

Comment: Suggest you create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way the conditionals are written

the last `else` will always be run when number isn't 3.

So when the number is one or two ... it gets to the `if(setTab ===3)` and since it isn't the `else` sets the value to empty string

A `switch` could be used. Or always `return` if it is one or two or use a series of `if/else`

```
  this.select = function(setTab) {
    this.tab = setTab;

    if (setTab === 1) {
      this.filtText = 'project';
    } else if (setTab === 2) {
      this.filtText = 'team';
    } else if (setTab === 3) {
      this.filtText = 'prof';
    } else {
      this.filtText = '';    
    };

  };
```

Or

```
this.select = function(setTab) {
    this.tab = setTab;

    if (setTab === 1) { this.filtText = 'project'; return;}
    if (setTab === 2) { this.filtText = 'team'; return;}
    if (setTab === 3) { this.filtText = 'prof'; }
    else this.filtText = '';
};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uDCWy3IJJkV62D4MwrOe?p=preview)**</kbd>